# HP Quality Center 12 LDAP

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

We have ALM 12.
I'm trying to find the site admin schema/ DB / Table name, unfortunately i couldn't find it after looking at `"C:\Program Files\HP\ALM\application\20qcbin.war\WEB-INF"`, there is a siteadmin xml file,  which is saying that the db name is : ALM12Site, but i can't find it.

I have to find the DB which is storing the LDAP server name, so i'll be able to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing but in ALM you can find almost identical configuration files in `\Program Files\..` and `\ProgramData\..` It doesn't help that by default `\ProgramData` is a hidden folder.

The one in `\Program Files\` are a backup copy of files used during install. The working configuration is under `\ProgramData\..`

And it's there that you should look for `siteadmin.xml`

But, I advise you against it, unless you are knowing precisely what are you trying to achieve. You may make changes to ALM schema which will make it unusable.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for you can find here:
%PROGRAMDATA%\HP\ALM\conf\qcConfigFile.properties